# How to add custom buttons to the Android 3.0+ System Bar?

Tags: android, button

Does anyone know if there is a way to add custom buttons to the Android System Bar in Android 3.0+ (Honeycomb/ICS)?

I would like to add an application-provided button to that menu, but I have not been able to locate any API functionality that will allow it.  I know that this area is sort of unofficially "off limits" to normal, non-system-level applicaitions, but I was wondering if anyone knew of a way to do this anyway?

Note: I am speaking specifically about the "System" bar that shows up along the bottom of the screen and *not* the "Action" bar which each app can customize at the TOP of the screen.

Let me know if you have any thoughts on this, thanks!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does anyone know if there is a way to add custom buttons to the Android System Bar in Android 3.0+ (Honeycomb/ICS)?

Sorry, this is not supported. You can add a `Notification` that will appear on the right side of the system bar, but not with the rest of the system buttons on the left.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation Mr. Murphy!  I was 99.999% certain this was the answer, but I just figured I would throw it out here for the slight chance that someone knew a way around it.  Thanks again!